# mysqltest adding and droping column parallelly

Tags: mysql

I have my own storage engine for mysql and I am trying to writing some test suite for it. Specifically, I want a test which can add and drop columns parallelly for one table, that is, while a thread is adding to table `employee` columns `c1, c2, c3,...,cn`, another thread should dropping columns `d1, d2, d3,...` (assuming there are already those columns). How can I do that.

Answer (score 0):

Hy Mate

Try:

```
ALTER TABLE foo
DROP COLUMN d1, 
ADD c1
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: I want to do that parallely